# Why is Windows 10 telling me that I have 0 free space on my D: drive, when I actually have > 10 GB?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

Often, especially when I'm running a long-running process that uses a lot of RAM, the process will get half way through then crash because Windows thinks there's no more available disk space. Then I restart the PC to discover everything is fine, there's still more than enough space for the process to finish. Why?

Does Microsoft assume that "everyone has a 500 GB or larger hard drive these days, so we can waste as much of their space as we like"? Well I have a 6 year old MacBook Air with a 128 GB SSD, and even the newer ones only come with 256 GB.

For example: I just tried to use Deluge to download a 16 GB torrent file on to my D: drive (system partition is C: as it is on 99% of PCs) while File Explorer was showing 18 GB of free space on that drive. Giving me a theoretical wiggle room of 2 GB, right?

No other programs running at the same time, no Windows Updates dl'ing in the background (as far as I can tell), no other obvious reasons for 2 GB to be inadequate margin. Yet the download stopped at 68%. I had to restart, force re-check in Deluge and continue before it happened again at 84%!

**Another** restart resulted in the dl finally completing and being left with the expected 2 GB of space on D:. So why is this happening?!?! Am I missing something really obvious here because I still don't get it...and it doesn't just happen with Deluge, it happens with all sorts of programs.

Oh and BTW, don't know if this is relevant but I've **never** seen my system RAM usage go above 80%...not even once. I only have 4 GB but that seems to be more than enough for what I do regularly.

Comment: We don't have nearly enough information to help you. What's that long-running process, is it something specific or anything that runs long enough? How does  it crash? Why do you have to reboot? How much used space does Explorer show before crash, after crush but before reboot and after reboot? Do you by any chance have pagefile configured on that drive?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. The reasons why you could be out of space are numerous. For example, lack of free RAM will cause Windows to use swap which could become pretty huge.

Comment: Sorry guys thought I was being detailed enough but obviously not! Anything that runs long enough will cause the problem, and "long enough" is usually ~30 mins or longer. It doesn't crash per se, but complains about no disk space in whatever fashion that program was designed to. I have to reboot to get Windows/the program to realise that there is still plenty of space available. Enough space for whatever I'm doing + extra before I start the process, 0 bytes remaining after but before reboot, many GB after reboot. I thought it might be the pagefile, but apparently there is none on D: :(

Comment: When you reboot the OS will run disk integrity checks which may roll back filesystem transactions that are allocating space. It is entirely possible the immediately prior to your crash there *was* no space left. Programs can allocate or lock disk space as they need it and a reboot will release it. We don't know what programs you are running or what you are doing so it is difficult to offer any help. It could be Windows Update temporarily allocating space, you downloading things or thousands of other programs.

Comment: @Mokubai Hmm interesting...thanks! I thought that this might be a performance feature of Win 10, like maybe it uses your SSD for swap space just to speed things up. But that wouldnt make sense anyway, since RAM is 100x faster than a storage device ever could be (although modern SSDs are starting to catch up from what I've read). Meh, I guess I'll just have to deal with it for now. But I'm still confused as to how I could e.g. have 18 GB free before starting a 16 GB dl, then the dl crashes half way through. Surely 2 GB is enough for whatever Windows is doing in the bg (no other progs running)?!

Comment: @Kenny83 - 2 GB on the system partition or system memory?  Edit your question...no comments

Comment: It depends on what the program does to do the download. If it downloads the 16GB as a temporary file somewhere and then copies it to the final location then obviously it will fail. I vaguely remember Internet Explorer doing this in the past. If the program simply renames the temporary file to the destination then you'd be fine and I know Firefox works that way. Depending on your version and setup of Windows installing programs, drivers or Windows Updates might also trigger the System Restore functionality to cordon off space. You really shouldn't be driving your system to little free space....

Comment: Storage space disappearing without any cause points to File History.  Use the appropriate tools to map disk space usage to determine what is using your storage space, and no, 2 GB isn’t enough disk space.

Comment: Fair enough guys, thanks for the advice. Trust me if I had the option, I'd buy the latest Dell XPS 13 and be done with this over-priced laptop that has a ridiculous SSD size for 2019. But unfortunately my bank account balance is much smaller than I'd like lol :P

Comment: Are you configuring deluge to preallocate the download file? This might solve your problem by ensuring that it only needs to write directly into the file instead of to a temporary file.

Comment: @shawn Yep. That's the default option.

Comment: Disk space will get even tighter soon.  Windows Insider Preview Jan 2019 has a "Reserved Space" option which will semi-permanently reserve multiple GB of space for the OS.  https://blogs.windows.com/blog/2019/01/09/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-18312/

Comment: Wonderful! Really looking forward to that, coz struggling to fit everything on my tiny hard drive isn't hard enough already!</angry sarcasm>

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons this happens, but the most critical piece you're missing is how downloads work.  When you are conventionally downloading a 16GB file, you may actually need 32GB free, because the file is downloaded as a "partial" download until it's complete, then it actually writes the completed download as a new file which is saved.  There are different download mechanisms, but if you watch the download progress in the folder where you're saving a conventional download, you can often see the partial download as it is marked in some way (e.g. "filename.partial").

When you are downloading Torrents, you have the additional factor that the pieces may come from different sources, and therefore be different sizes, each time you attempt the download.  So a Torrent download is more like "assembling" a file from pieces, than like a traditional download of an intact file.

The best explanation of this process that I could locate is at [How Torrent Downloading works](https://www.lifewire.com/how-torrent-downloading-works-2483513) .

In addition, there are other ways that your system temporarily consumes disk space until you restart.  Most visible are just temp files that are open while given applications are open, essentially the "working files", which are often removed on closing the app.  On a Mac, there is also swap file space;  there is a discussion at [Question about Mac restart freeing up disk space](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89517/why-do-i-get-back-more-disk-space-when-i-restart-my-macbook-on-mountain-lion-10) about this phenomenon, although not all the comments are technically correct.

Comment: OK so with Deluge set to use "Full Allocation", it doesn't allocate all space necessary and download straight into that space? This is how I'd do it if I wrote a torrent app :S